# convert multi line text log to CSV with Windows cmd or Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to convert a uniform multi line log file to a CSV, and nothing works. Please help! I'm on a Windows server, so it has to be a command line or a Powershell.

Input sample:

```
SERVICE_NAME: BDESVC
DISPLAY_NAME: BitLocker Drive Encryption Service
BDESVC hosts the BitLocker Drive Encryption service. BitLocker Drive Encryption provides secure startup for the operating system, as well as full volume encryption for OS, fixed or removable volumes. This service allows BitLocker to prompt users for various actions related to their volumes when mounted, and unlocks volumes automatically without user interaction. Additionally, it stores recovery information to Active Directory, if available, and, if necessary, ensures the most recent recovery certificates are used.  Stopping or disabling the service would prevent users from leveraging this functionality.
    TYPE          : 20 WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS 
    START_TYPE    : 3  DEMAND_START
    ERROR_CONTROL     : 1  NORMAL
    BINARY_PATH_NAME  : C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs
    LOAD_ORDER_GROUP  : 
    TAG       : 0
    DEPENDENCIES      : 
    SERVICE_START_NAME: localSystem
    FAIL_RESET_PERIOD : 900 seconds
    FAILURE_ACTIONS   : Restart DELAY: 60000 seconds
              : Restart DELAY: 60000 seconds
              : None    DELAY: 0 seconds

SERVICE_NAME: BFE
DISPLAY_NAME: Base Filtering Engine
The Base Filtering Engine (BFE) is a service that manages firewall and Internet Protocol security (IPsec) policies and implements user mode filtering. Stopping or disabling the BFE service will significantly reduce the security of the system. It will also result in unpredictable behavior in IPsec management and firewall applications.
    TYPE          : 20 WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS 
    START_TYPE    : 2  AUTO_START
    ERROR_CONTROL     : 1  NORMAL
    BINARY_PATH_NAME  : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork
    LOAD_ORDER_GROUP  : NetworkProvider
    TAG       : 0
    DEPENDENCIES      : RpcSs
    SERVICE_START_NAME: NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
    FAIL_RESET_PERIOD : 86400 seconds
    FAILURE_ACTIONS   : Restart DELAY: 120000 seconds
              : Restart DELAY: 300000 seconds
              : None    DELAY: 0 seconds
```

CSV Output needed (shown only the first event):

```
SERVICE_NAME,DISPLAY_NAME,DESCRIPTION,TYPE,START_TYPE,ERROR_CONTROL,BINARY_PATH_NAME,LOAD_ORDER_GROUP,TAG,DEPENDENCIES,SERVICE_START_NAME,FAIL_RESET_PERIOD,FAILURE_ACTIONS_1,FAILURE_ACTIONS_2,FAILURE_ACTIONS_3,
BDESVC,BitLocker Drive Encryption Service,"BDESVC hosts the BitLocker Drive Encryption service. BitLocker Drive Encryption provides secure startup for the operating system, as well as full volume encryption for OS, fixed or removable volumes. This service allows BitLocker to prompt users for various actions related to their volumes when mounted, and unlocks volumes automatically without user interaction. Additionally, it stores recovery information to Active Directory, if available, and, if necessary, ensures the most recent recovery certificates are used.  Stopping or disabling the service would prevent users from leveraging this functionality.",20 WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS,3  DEMAND_START,1  NORMAL,C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs,,0,,localSystem,900 seconds,Restart  DELAY: 60000 seconds,Restart    DELAY: 60000 seconds,None   DELAY: 0 seconds,
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  While there are many SO users that could write a script for you, SO is not a code writing service, but a question/answer forum.  You should make an attempt, post your code and ask specific questions about what isn't working.

Comment: ^^ this is very true and worth bearing in mind in future. I've answered but mostly because these kind of challenges always pique my curiosity. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To offer a different perspective from [Mark Wragg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2796058/mark-wragg), you can try using `Select-String` to capture the variables you need to output, rather than working off the format exactly as it is for these two specific cases.

You can try something like this:

```
$myArr = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\YourLogFile.txt") | Select-String -Pattern "SERVICE_NAME[\s\S]*?(?=SERVICE_NAME)" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value}
```

This will return an array of all the individual log entries, based on the assumption that `SERVICE_NAME` begins each entry. From there, you can loop through each entry in that array, and look for the values you would like to output to the CSV:

```
$myArr = @()
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\YourLogFile.txt") | Select-String -Pattern "SERVICE_NAME[\s\S]*?(?=(SERVICE_NAME)|($))" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value} | % { $myArr += `
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Type" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=TYPE          : ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value};
        "START_TYPE" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=START_TYPE    : ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value};
    }}
```

You can add as many properties into that hash table as you would like (ERROR_CONTROL, SERVICE_START_NAME, etc), and then use `Export-CSV' to write them to a file. There are two ways you can handle that, based on this solution:

```
$myArr | Select-Object Type,Start_Type | Export-CSV 'out.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

or add this to the end of the pipe, if you don't care to read it into a variable:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\YourLogFile.txt") | Select-String -Pattern "SERVICE_NAME[\s\S]*?(?=(SERVICE_NAME)|($))" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value} | % { `
    @([PSCustomObject]@{
        "Type" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=TYPE          : ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value};
        "START_TYPE" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=START_TYPE    : ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value};
    })} | Select-Object -Property Type,Start_Type | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\test\myout.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Just be sure to add all the properties you wish to export to `Select-Object`

Comment: and the final answer is: (thank you guys! ) It totally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. Bear in mind this makes some assumptions about your data and doing this sort of thing is always a bit hacky:

```
(Get-Content 'YourFile.log') -Replace '(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*)','$1=$2' -Split '\r\n\r\n' | ForEach-Object { 
    $Text = ($_ -split '\n') -Replace '\\','\\'
    $Text[2] = 'DESCRIPTION='+ $Text[2]
    $Result = $Text | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
    $Properties = [ordered]@{}

    $Headers = 'SERVICE_NAME','DISPLAY_NAME','DESCRIPTION','TYPE','START_TYPE','ERROR_CONTROL','BINARY_PATH_NAME','LOAD_ORDER_GROUP','TAG','DEPENDENCIES','SERVICE_START_NAME','FAIL_RESET_PERIOD','FAILURE_ACTIONS'
    $Headers | ForEach-Object { $Properties.Add($_,$Result.$_) }
    [PSCustomObject]$Properties

} | Export-CSV 'out.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

- Uses a regex `(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*)` to convert the first `:` and any space characters either side of it to an `=`. We do this so that we can later use the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet to convert the data to a hashtable object.
- Splits the data based on where there are two (Windows-style) carriage returns `\r\n\r\n` so we have a collection of the individual records
- Iterates through the records and splits the text in to individual lines. Replaces any single slashes with two slashes by using the (confusing looking) regex `'\\','\\'`. This is so that `ConvertFrom-StringData` isn't tripped up by the file paths.
- Takes the third line in the data and adds 'DESCRIPTION=' to the beginning of this line as otherwise this line is not in the expected name=value format.
- Returns the resultant text to a single string object via `Out-String` and then converts this to a hashtable via `ConvertFrom-StringData`.
- Because `ConvertFrom-StringData` reorders the fields alphabetically, creates a second `[ordered]` hashtable named `$Properties` which uses a predefined ordered list of the headers and then creates a PowerShell object from this.
- Exports the result to CSV.

Comment: I have been trying a bunch of scripts but they all failed. I will make sure I post them the next time I ask about something. Thank you! Wow, it's a lot longer than what I expected...

Comment: throws an error:                                                                                       Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At line:3 char:5
+     $Text[2] = 'DESCRIPTION='+ $Text[2]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: output file:     "SERVICE_NAME","DISPLAY_NAME","DESCRIPTION","TYPE","START_TYPE","ERROR_CONTROL","BINARY_PATH_NAME","LOAD_ORDER_GROUP","TAG","DEPENDENCIES","SERVICE_START_NAME","FAIL_RESET_PERIOD","FAILURE_ACTIONS"
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Seems like your input data isn’t quite formatted as shown in your question, the error suggests either you didn’t manage to read the file in with get-content or that the line separators aren’t newlines.

Comment: If you can share the actual input file somewhere (eg OneDrive) I could play around with why it’s not working. It’s hard to say otherwise.